# How do you properly define and use the phrase, "buy into"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, expressions, word-usage

I found this line while I was reading:

> That commercial said that this product would help me lose weight in one week. I’m not buying into that idea.

While I somehow understood the meaning of the whole sentence by reading between the lines, I could not grasp the whole idea of the phrase when I isolated it from the rest of the sentence.

I tried to find decent definitions on the web but they could not properly give the proper use of this phrase (since there seemed to be different views on it). Could anyone please enlighten me on this topic? Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Please provide some context on the usage you’re interested in.

Comment: I found this line while I was reading: "That commercial said that this product would help me lose weight in one week. I’m not buying into that idea." While I somehow understood the meaning of the whole sentence by reading between the lines, I could not grasp the whole idea of the phrase when I isolated it from the rest of the sentence. Thanks @Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example that Elliot Frisch gave was for the figurative use of "buy", not of the idiom "buy into".

**Buy into** (or **buy in**) has a more specific meaning:  to agree to/ approve a {project/course of action}.
See definition (2) at http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buy+in

It is often used in businees contexts, where someone proposing a project must get management **buy-in**  *(noun*) before starting the project.

This is still based on the literal sense of  "buy", since the management is implicitly approving the expenditure of funds, as well as time and resources, on the project.

Sometime this is called *blessing* the project, on the analogy of a religious blessing rite.  That is, a project can go forward once the "gods" in the executive suite have looked on it favorably, as something **worthwhile**.

Comment: I see your point Mr. @Brian Hitchcock. Thank you for explaining it clearly :)

Comment: I'm not convinced the business context is relevant to whether or not to include the preposition ***into*** after figurative ***buy** [an idea]*. I think it's effectively just an ***intensifier***. That's to say *I'm not buying that!* is the idiomatic standard for *I don't believe that!*, but the relatively "marked" form *I'm not buying **into** that!* more decisively conveys *I want to **keep well away from** that idea!* (I'm not even prepared to entertain it as a *possible* way of thinking).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the informal meaning of [*buy into*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buy+into) (from the free dictionary)

> To accept the truth or feasibility of: *The officer didn't buy my lame excuse for speeding.*

It's a metaphor in which one person is *selling* (an idea) and another is *buying*, or not, what the other is promoting.

Comment: Thank you so much for the swift response, Mr. @ElliotFrisch :)

Answer (score 0):

The word *buy* has a number of different senses (some of them idiomatic or colloquial) depending on context and associated words (like *in*, *into*, and *out*). Especially relevant to the sentence you use as your example are these definitions in Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary:

> **buy** ... *vt* ... **5 :** ACCEPT, BELIEVE {I don't *buy* that hooey} — often used with *into* ... **buy into :** to purchase a portion of or interest in {the TV network *bought into* its local football team}

The relevant meaning for your purposes is definition 5 ("ACCEPT, BELIEVE")—which is indeed the same response given in Elliott Frisch's answer—but a couple of additional points are worth making here. First, notwithstanding Merriam-Webster's comment that *buy* in this sense is often used with *into*, it is also often not used with *into* or any other helping word. For example:

> Spicoli says he worked all night on his essay, but I'm not buying it.

is a very common use of *buy* in the definition 5 sense. Second, the other meaning of "buying into" quoted from the Eleventh Collegiate above can raise problems of ambiguity in certain situations. Consider this example:

> Lester says he has a new scheme that will net him—and anyone who helps him set it up—millions of dollars, but I'm not buying into it.

Here is the speaker saying that he doesn't believe Lester's claim about the riches to be harvested from his new scheme? Or is he saying that he isn't going to purchase an interest in the scheme in order to profit from it later if it goes well?

Another variable (not noted by Merriam-Webster) is that the phrase "buying in" sometimes appears in place of "buying into" in the sense of purchasing a portion of some undertaking as an investment—as in the classic Swamp Dogg album from 1981, [*I'm Not Selling Out/I'm Buying In*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IXQVK2A).

Yet another phrase that in recent years has gained considerable popularity—in this case, as a term in business jargon—is *buy-in*, which refers to a commitment by participants in an endeavor to support it with their best efforts.

With all of these similar-sounding forms of *buy*, *buy in*, and *buy into*, it is a good idea to look very closely at the context of the remarks where the phrase appears, to help you figure out which of the group of meanings the speaker or writer actually intends.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. @Sven Yargs. This is quite a comprehensive explanation. I really appreciate it! :)